# Show that $\inf( (x_{k})_{k≥1})$, the infimum of $(x_{k})_{k≥1}$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let us consider a sequence of real numbers $(x_{k})_{k≥1}$ such that $0<x_{k}<w<1$ and $\lim_{k→∞} x_{k}>0$.

Show that $\inf ((x_{k})_{k≥1})$, the infimum of $(x_{k})_{k≥1}$ exists.

Comment: $\inf_{k\geq 1} \{x_k\}$ is not the same as $\min_{k\geq 1}\{x_k\}$.

Comment: @Cbjork: Yes correted.

Comment: A collection of real numbers that is bounded has an infimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1=x_1$. Let $A_1=\{i\,:\,x_i<a_1\}$. Inductively let $a_{i+1}=a_k$ where $k=\begin{cases}\min A_i & A_i \text{ nonempty} \\i & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and define $A_{i+1}=\{i\,:\,x_i<a_{i+1}\}$.

$(a_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence bounded below by $0$, so it converges. It must converge to $\inf_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\{x_k\}$.